# How to send html emails to gmail with php? yahoo works not gmail

Tags: php, html, email, gmail

I've been using php to send html emails to people daily for over a year and it has always worked until today, all the emails sent to gmail accounts just displayed the html code. I haven't changed any code recently. It always just displays the html code now in gmail instead of showing the hyperlinks and images.

Here's what it shows:

> Reply-To: updates@mysite.com
>
> MIME-Version: 1.0
>
> Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
> X-Mailer: PHP/5.3.2 Message-Id:
>   <20120426030303.E8B03A295@www1.mysite.com> Date: Wed, 25 Apr 2012
>   20:03:03 -0700 (PDT)

... etc.

What happened?
Did google change something?

Comment: Plz accept some of your questions!

Comment: I never noticed those buttons. And I thought it was saying nobody accepted me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has also started happening for me since yesterday: 25/04/2012.
I have been receiving the same email, same format daily for the last few years - and yesterday seized to stop displaying in HTML format!

Comparing the message content - only thing different I can see from a previous email that displayed correctly is the addition after the authentication results of the following:

> Date: Wed, 25 Apr 2012 17:31:23 -0700 (PDT) Message-Id:
>   <4f98975b.9cecd80a.7d2a.66b3SMTPIN_ADDED@mx.google.com>

Could this have anything to do with the cause?

Scrap the above - take a look at this stie: http://johndoesdesign.com/blog/2012/php/getting-your-php-html-email-to-render-in-gmail/

It appears the cause is the `"\r\n"` - use just `"\n"` instead.  Why this would just start happening out of the blue - something must have changed gmail's end.  I've tried this and solved the issue for me.  Hope it does for you.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this could help u

[Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)

and like Lawrence said, accept your questions so ppl could answer faster and better

Comment: I'm not using any libraries, just using the mail() command and I would like to keep doing it that way if that's still possible to send html emails to gmail accounts that way. It isn't giving an error.

Comment: Hooray for spending time writing code to solve problems that other people have already solved! No, wait. Not hooray.