# Need to insert some html in a mail($email php generate email

Tags: php, html, email

I would like to insert some html in the email that my php file generate after a form.
Here the part of the email:

```
mail($email, 
     "www.icecream-icecream.com", 
     "Thank you for your message,
           within 24 hours you will receive a personally dedicated email. Bye",
      "From: info@...."
   );
```

Where You can read "thank you for your message..." I would like basic customize with html.
Why?
Because I want to insert Thai characters that without html will not properly send.

Thanks if you know how to do it, thanks anyway if don't know.
I am very new here.

Comment: Use proper `headers`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send HTML in email via PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238953/send-html-in-email-via-php)

Comment: Do some basic research before asking a question, for example a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+html+mail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
$subject = "HTML email";
$message = "<html><head><title>HTML email</title></head><body><p></p></body></html>";
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

This way you may put the html in the `$message`. [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for help. I did Google around and also in this forum and I do admit there were similar answers. But maybe the way Varunsinghal expose the code was the only one I could apply to my case or maybe I was not just well prepared to understand others solutions. This was really clear. Great!