# how to set url which has sent to the mail and that link should be redirect on another url in php

Tags: php, mysql, email, url, redirect

I have URL which is sent to the given email. However, I would like user clicking that URL to be redirected to another URL.

I have tried the below code for sending mail,but I don't know how to create a URL which will redirect to another page.

```
<?php

$send_link=getLink("http://www.google.com",array("referral"=>"123","mobilenumber"=>"1234"));
echo $send_link;


function getLink($url,$params=array(),$use_existing_arguments=false)
{

    if($use_existing_arguments) $params = $params + $_GET;

    if(!$params) return $url;
    $link = $url;

    if(strpos($link,'?') === false) $link .= '?';
    //If there is no '?' add one at the end
    elseif(!preg_match('/(\?|\&(amp;)?)$/',$link)) $link .= '&amp;';
    //If there is no '&' at the END, add one.
    $params_arr = array();
    foreach($params as $key=>$value)
    {

        if(gettype($value) == 'array')
        {
            //Handle array data properly
            foreach($value as $val)
            {
                $params_arr[] = $key . '[]=' . urlencode($val);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            $params_arr[] = $key . '=' . urlencode($value);
        }

    }

    $link .= implode('&amp;',$params_arr);
    return $link;
}

$user_id='1';
$get_referred_user=mysqli_query($con,"select * from Phone_Book_Email where contact_id='$user_id'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($get_referred_user) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_referred_user))
    {
        $email_id=$row['email_id'];
        echo $email_id;
        $to      = $email_id;
        $subject = 'test';
        $message = 'URL- '.$send_link;
        $headers = 'From: Hubster@hubster.com' . "\r\n" .    'Reply-To: Hubster@hubster.com' . "\r\n" .    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        //header("Location:http://www.facebook.com");
        //header("refresh: $time_in_seconds; url=http://www.facebook.com");
    }

}


?>
```

Please suggest me guys what I have to do here for redirecting user clicking one url to another url.

Comment: Do you mean that you want one link to be shown in the message and another address to be opened in browser when link is clicked? Or are you looking to redirect HTTP requests from one address to another?

Comment: hey @Abdael5 thanks for reply..you are getting correct,I want to one click to be shown in the message and that link should be redirect on another link...

Comment: Are both the links on your server ?

Comment: No @Akshay,I am just trying with another link , like 1st link will be www.google.com and 2nd link will be www.facebook.com.

Comment: @Neha
`<a href="link1.php">Link2.php</a>` Something like this?

Comment: @Akshay ,ya like this only,but how can I do like this.

Comment: @Neha
Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have one link pointing to another adress you will have to use in your email message HTML tags.

This means that in the header of your email you should use additionally:

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Than in your message you can simply use HTML tags:

```
<HTML><BODY><A HREF="$link_a">$link_b</A></BODY></HTML>
```

where $link_a - is uri of redirect, and $link_b is link to be displayed.

**Update 1 relating to the code in the comment:**

As to the code provided by you in the comment there is one mistake in line

```
$message = 'URL- '."<A HREF=\"$send_link\">$link_b</A>";
```

it should look like this:

```
$message = "URL- "."<A HREF=\"$send_link\">$link_b</A>";
```

or best:

```
$message = "URL- "."<A HREF=\"".$send_link."\">".$link_b."</A>";
```

**Update 2 full code:**

You were also missing "\r\n" after `X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion()` which could resulted in email not being formatted. Try something like this:

```
     $to = $email_id; 
    $subject = 'test';
    $send_link = 'http://google.com';
    $link_b = 'http://facebook.com';
 $message = "URL- "."<A HREF=\"".$send_link."\">".$link_b."</A>"; 
 $headers = 'From: Hubster@hubster.com' . "\r\n" .
 'Reply-To: Hubster@hubster.com' . "\r\n" .
 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion()."\r\n";
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

You may also want to refer to information provided here: 
[Send HTML in email via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238953/send-html-in-email-via-php)

Comment: Hey @Abdel5,I have tried your code , it should be like this only no.. ?      $to      = $email_id;
$subject = 'test';
$message = 'URL- '."<A HREF="{$send_link}">{$link_b}</A>";
;
$headers = 'From: Hubster@hubster.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: Hubster@hubster.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

Comment: Please remove { } tags as shown in the updated reply.

Comment: hey @Abdel5 if I am using $headers which you suggest me ,message not sending on email but if i am using without that $headers it's working,message sending.

Comment: I have tried your updated code,message is sending and that link looks like this ..<A HREF="http://www.google.com?referral=123&amp;mobilenumber=123">http://www.facebook.com</A>

Comment: This is probably because after 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion()' you should have "\r\n".

Comment: Thank you so much :-) @Abdel5 ,its working perfectly fine for me , i have tried your updated answer and its working.

Comment: hey @Abdel5 do u now how can i get the values from that link ,if that link will be click by someone.???

Comment: Neha, I don't quite understand your question. Possibly you could write a bit more about your problem in another question (just to not make side discussions here) and link it here so I will be able to see if I can help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85195/discussion-between-abdel5-and-neha).

Answer (score 2):

It's honestly very simple what you need.

```
<a href="http://facebook.com">google.com</a>
```

So in this case, it will show you google.com as the `href` link, but when you click on it, you'd go to facebook.

Comment: it would be like this no..                                                       $message = 'URL- '."<a href=$send_link>$link_b</a>";

Comment: hey @Akshay, I have tried your code the message which i'm getting in my mail its lokking like this..<A HREF="http://www.google.com?referral=123&amp;mobilenumber=123">http://www.facebook.com</A>