# HTML tags and inline styling not working inside PHP email

Tags: php, html, css, email

I am using PHP to send emails. For some reason, the `h1` tags are not working. Here is a sample mail.

```
$to      = 'user@gmail.com';
$subject = "Subject";
$header  = "from: Website <contact@website.com>\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: contact@website.com\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<img style="margin-bottom:20px;" src="link to image"/>';
$message .= '<h1 style="text-align:center;">How are you using Website?</h1>';
$message .= '</body></html>';
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
  return true;
}
```

The `li` tags or `a` tag that I used in the email show up nicely. Why are `h1` tags not working? Also, the text is not aligned to `center`. So, I guess inline styling is not working either.

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238953/send-html-in-email-via-php and https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Comment: Missing `.`, it should be `$message .= '<img style="margin-bottom:20px;" src="link to image">';`

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Thanks. However, it still does not work.

Comment: @Martin I have read that question. I am also setting all the headers correctly. I followed http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/ which was mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Your html looks broken on the image tag. Make sure you close it with the /> at the end

Comment: @DevinPrejean Thanks. But that did not help either.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked well...

Comment: what email client are you using to view the emails? web based like gmail or client such as outlook?

Comment: Maybe you should explain what "not working" means.

Comment: I am using Gmail and by not working I mean the text inside `h1` tags still shows up as a `p` text without any change in size or alignment (It should have been aligned centrally). Thanks.