# Variable in Bold

Tags: php, variables, post

Is there some kind of short code for the output of a variable to be **bold**?

```
$message = "Algemene informatie";
$message .= "Volledige naam : ".$_POST['volledigenaam'];
```

The first one, Algemene informatie, needs to be **bold**, but it only displays text, not HTML.

Comment: No it is not. PHP is a programming language. You need HTML/CSS.

Comment: php doesn't apply visual effects, you're looking for css, or, if needed be, you could do `<strong> ....TEXT HERE....</strong>` or `<b> ....TEXT HERE....</b>` which is html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$message = "<strong>Algemene informatie</strong>"; 
$message .= "Volledige naam : ".$_POST['volledigenaam'];
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work. The output is literally text so <strong>Algemene informatie</strong> not **Algemene informatie**

Comment: Are you try to show this in mail body or on screen?

Comment: Yes, it's for mail. I didn't mention that. My mistake

Comment: add this line $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";    check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238953/send-html-in-email-via-php