# Why is the text in an email sent via php being put on a new line?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm writing an emailing script for order confirmation for customers of my website. I'm having a problem where the total of the order displayed in the email is being placed on a new line, however no new line is in the code. I've attached an image of what is happening.[image]

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['order'])) {
    $to = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'] .",";
    $order = $_POST['order'];
    $trackingNumber = $_POST['trackingNumber'];
    $totalAmount = "Your total was: $".$_POST['totalAmount'];

    if(!empty($to) && !empty($name) && !empty($order)) {

      $subject = 'From the band.it team ';
      $text = "My name is Bobby and I am a part of band.it's fulfillment Team! We recieved your order and are working to process it from our Gainesville, Florida facility. Feel free to reach out to us at any point with any comments, questions, or concerns. You can find our contact infomation at the bottom of this email.";
        $body = "Hey ".$name."\r\n".$text."\r\nYour order will contain:\r\n".$order."\r\n";
      $body = $body.$totalAmount;
      $body = $body."\r\nYou can track your package through USPS with this number:\r\n".$trackingNumber."\r\n";
      $body = $body."\r\nYou can view any order you've made with us via going to the following link with your tracking number handy!\r\nhttps://camerabandit.com/findAnOrder/";
      $body = $body."\r\n\r\nThanks again for your support of the band.it team, and reach out to us anytime by sending an email to contact@camerabandit.com";
      $headers = 'Order Confirmed';

      if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
        echo 'Mail has been sent';
      } else {
        echo 'Mail failed to send';
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best guess is that `$_POST['totalAmount']` contains a line break.
You may want to [trim()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) it:

```
$totalAmount = "Your total was: $".trim($_POST['totalAmount']);
```

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest a table to enhance the display of the message also check your var i think it contains \r \n you can use this to trim it

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $string));
```

Comment: I've been looking for a way to make it much prettier, so I'm entirely open to suggestions. Could you please explain what you mean by table?

Comment: since your email is plain html use <table> tag to sort it and display it more elegantly

Comment: Whenever I include html in my email it shows up as plain text, i.e: <html> tags. Why is this?

Comment: you need to simply fix your header check this example :)

Comment: $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238953/send-html-in-email-via-php for more reference

Answer (score 1):

The part of the body directly before it is:

```
$body = "Hey ".$name."\r\n".$text."\r\nYour order will contain:\r\n".$order."\r\n";
```

So that ends with

```
\r\n
```

That's where your linebreak is...