# PHP analogue for rails html_safe

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

What command in php does what `html_safe` in `Ruby on rails`?

I have just found `htmlspecialchars`, but it doesn't do what i need

I just want to use im my mailer `<h1><? 'php some php code'.html_safe?> </h1>`.

Comment: What do you need? Do you want to HTML encode a String? Or do you want to reverse the encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing rails, I had to lookup the function. From what I understood, it basically asserts that the string is "fine"/is not a threat. Again, I don't know how it works in rails, but in PhP, every string is assumed safe, and it's the dev who has to take measures if he considers a string could be unsafe (using, for instance, htmlspecialchars ).

If all I said sounds right, you would want to simple echo the string

```
<h1><?php echo $string ?></h1>
```

or, using the

```
<h1><?= $string ?></h1>
```

If you want to insert it as a link, you have to manually write it as

```
<h1><a href="<?= $string ?>"></a></h1>
```

Additionally, if the string was an encoded url, you'd want to use

```
<?= urldecode($string) ?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: the main problem is - in my Gmail view it displayed as raw html code

Comment: aaaah I see, so your email is being sent literally as <h1>(something)</h1> ? What mailer are you using,  the default php mail() function?

Comment: ye,default mail func

Comment: This is what you're looking for then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238953/send-html-in-email-via-php