# Mail getting with HTML tags

Tags: php, html

My mail function is working fine, delivering mail after filling the form.

But the output in the mail is with HTML tags as shown attached.

Here is my code.

```
<php  if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {
$admin_email = "abcdef@gmail.com";
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$subject = $_REQUEST['salespersonname'];
$location = $_REQUEST['location'];
$noofbags = $_REQUEST['noofbags'];
$print = '<div>Location : $location<br />No of Bags : $noofbags</div>';
$comment = $print;

mail($admin_email, "$subject", $comment, "From:" . $email);
echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
}
?>
```

[image]

How can i get Output like this.

Location : Hyderabad

No of Bags : 50

Comment: You have to pass `$headers` for HTML tag.

Comment: You need to add $headers 
`
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send HTML in email via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238953/send-html-in-email-via-php)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below Headers to send email with HTML tags:

```
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

**Updated Code:**

```
<php  if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {
$admin_email = "abcdef@gmail.com";
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$subject = $_REQUEST['salespersonname'];
$location = $_REQUEST['location'];
$noofbags = $_REQUEST['noofbags'];
$print = '<div>Location : $location<br />No of Bags : $noofbags</div>';
$comment = $print;
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

mail($admin_email, "$subject", $comment, "From:" . $email, $headers);
echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
}
?>
```

Hope this will be help.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set header's

```
   $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following headers :

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Pass `$headers` as 4th parameter in `mail` function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Content-type header in your email message:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

and pass into

```
mail($admin_email, "$subject", $comment, "From:" . $email, $headers);
```

Your message body also needs to be contained in `<html>` tags.