# not send link in mail using php

Tags: php

I want to send confirmation link to new users. I used this code to send mail (confirmation link)

```
            $to = $email;
            $subject = "Verify Your Account";               


            $actual_link = "http://myorchidkart.com/simplepay/verify_email.php?hash=" . $hash;

            $message = "<a href ='".$actual_link."'>" . $actual_link . "</a>";



            $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "From: ". $from. "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from. "\r\n";                

            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

but there is no confirmation link, only text but no link 
how can I solve this ...?

mail is look like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIlhU.png)

Comment: Seems to be [okay, judging by this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238953/send-html-in-email-via-php). Why did you post your email address on a public site, btw?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the mail you receive using this code?

Comment: change `hash` to `'.$hash.'`

Comment: The code looks fine. Most likely the fact that GMail detected it as a possible scam is relevant - it's probably not making the link clickable so you don't click it accidentally.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on Not a spam button?

Comment: thats complete....thanks  programmingArrow