# Formatting String within Variable PHP

Tags: php, string, html-email

Is it possible to format the string within a variable within PHP script.

The following script sends an email to the user. The part shown is my entire body of the email including my signature. I want to bold or change the font size of my signature and everything I've tried didn't work.

I tried including  within the string, but it just reads the code and not implementing it. Tried to look over all the web to see if there's a possibility, but all the results show echo......

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['button_1'])){
        $to = $_POST['email'];
        $from = 'xxxxx <xxxx@xxxxx.edu>';
        $subject = "Thank you for your interest";
        $message ="Name" . "\n" . "Work" . "\n" . "Position" . 
                    "\n" . "(xxx) xxx-xxxx" . "\n" . "xxxx@xxxx.edu";
        $headers="From:" . $from; mail($to, $subject, $message, headers);
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); 
    }
?>
```

Trying to format "Name" within $message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send HTML in email via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238953/send-html-in-email-via-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use html in your text body.
For example, to make text to be bold you should use:

```html
$message = "<b>Your text here</b>";
```

To enable html in your message your should set these headers:

```html
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```

Comment: When I do that, it will bold everything after <b>xxx</b>, but it doesn't show the text inside the <b></b>. This happens when I add the break <br>, so I was wondering if that's what is causing this issue.

Comment: @BeginnerScripter do you know html?

Comment: Yes I do know html.

Comment: @BeginnerScripter you can your this code $message = "Not bold text<b>Not bold text</b>Not bold text";

Comment: @BeginnerScripter did my answer helped you?Please, choose my answer as the best.

Comment: Ok will do, appreciate your help. Thanks!