# Php html mail not displaying in html

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send an **html email**. Mail is working properly but not going as html email and it is just displaying `".$message."`. The data is coming from the mysql database.

My script is as follows:

```
$to       = $email;
$subject  = $subject;
$message  = "$message";

$htmlContent = '
<html>
<body>
".$message."
<br /><br />Regards<br /><b>TM</b>
</body>
</html>';
$headers  = 'From: myemail@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

if(mail($to, $subject, $htmlContent, $headers))
echo "Mail Sent";
else
echo "Problem sending email";
```

Comment: Interpolation is not done in single-quoted strings, putting double-quotes inside the single-quoted string does not change that

Comment: Are you sure you want to build all that stuff from scratch? There a tons of superb libraries like Swiftmailer that will take care of all the internals of mails

Comment: i tried to with phpmailer. But i dont know what was the problem, always i got error stating smtp error.

Comment: i was trying phpmailer from localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixed single and double quotes. Use only one type when concatenating strings.

```
$htmlContent = "
<html>
<body>
".$message."
<br /><br />Regards<br /><b>RainbowCTM</b>
</body>
</html>";
```

Comment: Its displaying now. But not displaying html mail. Its just showing with the html tags.

Comment: In what program are you displaying the e-mail? In Gmail and Thunderbird, the HTML is displayed correctly. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238953/send-html-in-email-via-php

Answer (score 0):

To complete previous answer, there is a huge difference between single and double quotes:

- Single quote not analyze characters inside, so if you did: `echo '$message'`, it just display `$message`.
- Double quotes analyze characters inside, so if you did: `echo "$message"`, it displays the content of `$message` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Finwe is totally right. 
Explanation: single quotes always take the string as it is without processing variables or metasigns like \t or \n.

just a hint in addition: try using only `\n` and not `\r\n` since there was a bug in some PHP-version that produced erros. even if this is not a problem at the moment, it might become one after an update (depending on your PHP-version).