# How to prevent hyperlins showing up in gmail message

Tags: php, html

I am sending emails to gmail account. The message has a link. I'd like the link does not show up. Below is the part of the message. Gmail will show this part as it is, but I'd like gmail shows as `Please ***click here*** to upload your application form.`

```
Please <a href='http://www.mywebsite.com'>click here </a> to upload your application form.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Send it as an HTML email.

Comment: Maybe this thread would be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238953/send-html-in-email-via-php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue here might be because of missing headers for content type. Look at the following example:

```
$to = 'test@test.com';

$subject = 'PHP Mail Sending';

$headers = "From: scripts@email.com \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: no-reply@email.com \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

$message = '<p>Hello, this is to check PHP mail function</p>';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

In above code, the line `$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";` tells the mailer and the recipient that the email contains are well formed HTML

Answer (score 1):

Before sending your mail make sure you have selected the the mail format as HTML.
You can find this according to your respective platform.