# Send HTML through mail() PHP using mailx

Tags: php, html, header, mailx

I installed mailx to send mails, I am able to send  mails through PHP using this function.

```
mail($to_email, $subject, $message, $header)
```

The thing is that I receive the html as attachment.
Then if I just

```
mail($to_email, $subject, 'hello world', $header)
```

I got plain text.

How can I send the mail as html. I thing that mailx is ignoring headers.
I am working on centos 7

I tryied config sendmail to do this, but I cant change the setfrom paramenter, because I am relaying to a smtp server which only use an specific email to send notifications.

This works perfect if I use mail in windows, the problem happen with mailx in centos.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send HTML in email via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238953/send-html-in-email-via-php)

Comment: How are you using `mailx` to send mail from PHP?

Comment: Do you have `Content-type: text/html` in the header?

Comment: In php.ini i refer to mailx instead sendmail. And yes i have content-type html