# How to do newline email body in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to send some information on mail body. When I try its works but Google shows trimmed content(...).

My code is like this:

```
$name = $e->name;
$code=$request->code;
 $mes2="loretmtext,";
        $mes3="loremtext";
        $mes4="Code:".$code;
        $mes5="e:".$name;
$mes6="text"


//and i send mail function
$msg= $mes2."<br />".$mes3."<br />".$mes4."<br />".$mes5."<br />".$mes6."<br />";
```

How can i solve?

Comment: Show us the code that handles sending the email. Are you using Laravel’s built-in methods?

Answer (score 0):

Need to add `"Content-Type: text/html;` in header mail request to use html tag `<br />` in you massage
look this:
[Send HTML in email via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238953/send-html-in-email-via-php)