# sending mail through phpmailer and its working properly but the problem is i have inserted one templet in it and i am receiving code of that templet

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

```
<?php   
function sendCOTP($REmail,$RVID) {
                $to      = $REmail;
                    $subject = 'Allloooooooooooo Bhindiiiiiii';
                    ob_start();
                    include './mailtemplet.php';
                    $body = ob_get_clean();
                    
                    $message = 'Dear,sir'
                            . 'Guess what ??? '.$RVID.' venue that you checked earlear is now finallyyy available so check it out and book it before again it get booked '
                            . 'Thank you'
                            . 'team venueazy';
                    $headers = 'From: bookvenue01@gmail.com'       . "\r\n" .
                                 'Reply-To: bookvenue01@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
                                 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

                    mail($to, $subject,$body, $message, $headers);
}
```

?>

so here everything is working fine but the templet which i have included that is not working like i am getting html code instead of that templet so need help with that how can i solve this issue.

thank you in advance.[Mail screenshot where i am getting html code instead of templet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpvpS.png)

need help is how can i make "IsHTML(true);" in my code?

Comment: You can't use `isHTML` because you're not using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). PHPMailer handles all this kind of formatting for you, plus it's a lot safer than using `mail()` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function sendCOTP($REmail,$RVID) {
$to = $REmail;

```
                    $subject = 'Venue is Available';

                    $headers = 'From:bookvenue01@gmail.com';
                    $headers .= 'Reply-To: bookvenue01@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

                    $email_template = './mailtemplet.html';
                    
                    $message = file_get_contents($email_template);

                    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```

This link will help you.
[Send HTML in email via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238953/send-html-in-email-via-php)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to include a header when submitting, add this to your code after Reply-To

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

use this meta tag inside your head tag .you must specify content type.else it can be take it as string.that's why your whole code displayed in mail.

```html
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />
```