# How do I debug curl issues (CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, text/html display) when a message is sent out successfully?

Tags: c, rest, mime-types, libcurl

I am successfully sending a mime message using libcurl. However, in the received email I can only see the "username" in the From: field.

```
    curlCode_ = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM,    from_field);
    recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, (const char *)to_);
    recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, cc.str().c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);
```

I assume its a security feature at gmail, ensuring that the sender is always shown in the From field.
Another issues is that I send out a multi-part mime message with an alt text portion. In zoho mail, I can view the HTML, however gmail always shows the text part.

For reference, I make sure the HTML comes before the text.

```
    /* Build the mime message. */
    mime = curl_mime_init(curl);

    /* The inline part is an alternative proposing the html and the text
       versions of the e-mail. */
    alt = curl_mime_init(curl);

    /* HTML message. */
    part = curl_mime_addpart(alt);
    curl_mime_data(part, html_body_.c_str(), CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);
    curl_mime_type(part, "text/html");

    /* Text message. */
    part = curl_mime_addpart(alt);
    curl_mime_data(part, body_.c_str(), CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);

    /* Create the inline part. */
    part = curl_mime_addpart(mime);
    curl_mime_subparts(part, alt);
    curl_mime_type(part, "multipart/alternative");
    slist = curl_slist_append(NULL, "Content-Disposition: inline");
    curl_mime_headers(part, slist, 1);
```

The code is rather long and in multiple classes, so I can post any code deemed relevant to avoid clutter. Essentially I am unsure how to debug this.

Comment: For reference, I make sure the HTML comes before the text.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I changed it to C.

Comment: As a reference, similar problems involving gmail. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897180/gmail-does-not-render-html-in-email

https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/curl/curl/5748/666491251

Comment: I cannot mark my answer - stackexchange does not like me enough. So perhaps someone else can mark this --> 

The text part has to be before the html part. Now both zohomail and gmail display the html.

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem - The text part of a multi-format MIME has to be before the html part. Now both zohomail and gmail display the html.

A more general answer relating to libcurl debugging - I use the curl program instead. Use -libcurl option to generate C code that can be used in your C/C++ project. There are sample curl commands available with most REST APIs.